# Ruby: Iterating through dir's and files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, loops, directory

I wrote the following script to iterate through a directory, it's subdirectories and their files:

```
    def self.search_files_in_dir_for(dir, strings)
        results = {}
        puts "Initializing test ..."
        Dir.foreach(dir) do |file|
            next if file == '.' or file == '..'
            puts 'TEST: Testing dir "' + dir + "/" + file + '"'
            if File.file?(file)
                puts 'TEST: Testing "' + dir + "/" + file + '"'
                line_number = 0
                IO.foreach(file) do |line|
                    line_number = line_number + 1
                    if strings.any? { |string| line.include?(string) }
                        string = strings.detect { |string| line.include?(string) }
                        puts source = file + ":" + line_number.to_s
                        results[source] = string
                    end
                end
            elsif File.directory?(file)
                # Search child directories
                search_files_in_dir_for(File.join(dir, file), strings)
            end
        end
    end
```

Given the followiing dir + file structure:

```
- views
  - application
    - abcdefg
      - _partial2.html.erb
    - _partial1.html.erb
  - layouts
    - application.html.erb
```

and when passing the path of the `views` directory as `dir`, I get that output:

```
Initializing test ...
TEST: Testing dir "views/application"
TEST: Testing dir "views/layouts"
```

I would expect something like this:

```
Initializing test ...
TEST: Testing dir "views/application"
TEST: Testing dir "views/application/abcdefg"
TEST: Testing "views/application/abcdefg/_partial2.html.erb"
TEST: Testing "views/application/_partial1.html.erb"
TEST: Testing dir "views/layouts"
TEST: Testing "views/layouts/application.html.erb"
```

What am I doing wrong in that script?

Comment: Are you familiar with `Dir.glob("./**/*")` which will give you a list of all directories and files?

Comment: @maxple no    .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pathname#Glob

A noticeably shorter version, using [`Pathname`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) and [`Pathname.glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-c-glob):

```
require 'pathname'
files, dirs = Pathname.glob('**/*').partition(&:file?)
```

It gives you two arrays : one with all the files in the current directory, the other with all the subfolders.

For a specific `dir` :

```
files, dirs = Pathname.glob(File.join(dir, '**/*')).partition(&:file?)
```

You'd just need to parse the content of `files`

## Grep or ack?

It looks like you're trying to replicate [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), [`ack`](https://beyondgrep.com/) or [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

## Your code, repaired

Here's a modified version of your code. The biggest problem was that `file` was a relative path. `File.file?(file)` was always returning `false` :

```
@results = {}
def search_files_in_dir_for(dir, strings)
  Dir.foreach(dir) do |file|
    complete_path = File.join(dir, file)
    next if file == '.' or file == '..'
    if File.file?(complete_path)
      puts "TEST: Testing '#{complete_path}'"
      line_number = 0
      IO.foreach(complete_path) do |line|
        line_number = line_number + 1
        if strings.any? { |string| line.include?(string) }
          string = strings.detect { |string| line.include?(string) }
          source = complete_path + ":" + line_number.to_s
          @results[source] = string
        end
      end
    else
      # Search child directories
      search_files_in_dir_for(complete_path, strings)
    end
  end
end

search_files_in_dir_for(..., [..., ...])

p @results
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I totally understand your point. Both of your solutions work - didn't knew about `pathname` so far. One (unexpected) problem though, I appended it to the post.

Comment: @jonhue: `**` already means "any depth". `'**/*'` will be enough for any depth. As for your `nil`, I don't see any reason why it should be different than in your test string.

Comment: Hm.. When I add `puts` to that line, I always end up with something like `:23`

Comment: I found out that I needed to call `to_s` on the pathname. That problem only occurred in the shorter version. Thank's for helping me!

Comment: You could use `[file, line_number].join(' : ')` to avoid calling `to_s`